# Searching two title fields with Select fields form with Solspace Super Search

Tags: ee2, solspace, supersearch, ee

With Solspace Super Search the manual says to use name='title" to search the title field. The issue is the results URL simply favors and outputs only the second select statement so `title=whatevervalue` whereas you want `title=whatevervalue&title=anothervalue`.

How do you deal with searching for two title fields from two different channels?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

```
<select channel="workplace" name="title" class="Textbox4" >
                    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                    {exp:channel:entries channel="workplace" sort="asc" dynamic="no" orderby="title"}
                    <option value="{url_title}"  >{title}</option>
                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                </select>

                    {exp:channel:entries channel="places" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no" category="1"}
<option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option value="{url_title}" >{title}</option>
                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                    </select>
{/exp:super_search:search}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `&&` after your field values:

```
<option value="{title}&&">{title}</option>
```

In Super Search, this can be used to make "AND" searches (eg. title A *AND* B)

Since you want to search more than one title at once, you need your field to allow an *array* of data. You can do this with a select field that accepts multiple values or with checkboxes. Eg:

```
<select name="title[]" multiple="multiple">
```

**Note**: Notice the brackets `[]` next to `title`: this is needed to send an *array* of data instead of a *string* of data. That's just how HTML forms work.

**Note 2**: In your select field, you have the other following issues:

- `channel=""` is not a valid attribute for select fields in HTML.
- If you're searching in *titles*, you need to use `value="{title}"` and not `value="{url_title}"`. If you're searching for a *url_title* instead, `value="{url_title}"` would be used.
- You're missing an opening `<select>` tag before your second `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair, if you need two select fields (if you need one select field, you have a closing `</select>` field too many.
- You have a leftover closing `{/exp:super_search:search}` tag in your code. You should remove that (btw, `{exp:super_search:search}` is often not needed in Super Search search forms)

Comment: Thank you. Everything is working much better, but the two select fields are not properly working in terms AND/OR functionality with the results they return. The "work" will return results even though those people don't live in that city. work="Building"&workplaces=South/